# Remove .php and id from url and replace with slash make a seo friendly url

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

**product?cat_id=28**

to

**product/28**

Please tell me in brief how it work and what changes will be done by mine.

Answer (score 0):

Use htaccess RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)/?$ product.php?cat_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: it can't work.please suggest anything else and thanks for help.